# Pandas: Creating data frames with non-repeating matches of two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matching

Assume following simple dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Max', 'Ethan', 'Karen', 'Carl', 'Jenny']})
```

For the purpose of *matching* tennis partners over the summer, I need to create one or multiple data frames, where matches of each two are created I the following way:

```
John  Max
Max   John
Ethan Caren
Caren Ethan
Carl  Jenny
Jenny Carl
...
```

We do this in order to *inform each party* about his or her opponent, every month. The matching can be randomised, it does not have to follow a given order. However, there is one important criterium: Matches are *not allowed to repeat*, they can only happen once. I realised that np.roll is not the best, as matches repeat when new entries are added. I thought something alongside `itertools.combinations(df, 2)` and working with a css that creates unique id (hash?) of previous matches could be it?

**What's the best solution to that?**

Note: It can happen that new entries are added to `df` during the season.

Comment: Read this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament There is no need to create then eliminte

Comment: Why wouldn't this work for you? pd.DataFrame(it.combinations(df['name'],2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the order to players in a game matters (i.e. a game John vs Max is different than Max vs John - as in the example you provided) here is one way to do it:

```
df["temp"] = 1
matches = pd.merge(df, df, on="temp").drop("temp", axis=1)
matches.columns = ["player_1", "player_2"]
matches = matches.query("player_1 != player_2").reset_index(drop=True)
```

If, on the other hand, order to players in a game does not matter (that is John should play with Max only once) then this should work:

```
df_lst = []
for i in range(len(df) - 1):
    temp = df.iloc[i+1:].assign(player_2=df.iloc[i, 0])
    df_lst.append(temp)

matches = pd.concat(df_lst).reset_index(drop=True)
matches.rename({"name": "player_1"}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```